# redirect using htaccess angular js

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I have a website created using angular js.I need to show one page when user request one url.
for example 
when the url is `mydomain.com/assets` then it shuld show this page  `mydomain.com/article/1234`

I have added teh bellow htaccess,but it throws 500 error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.assets)$ index.html#/article/1234 [L] // here i add redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html#/$1 [L]
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.assests)$ mydomain.com/index.html#/article/1234 [R=301,L]
```